# Rmd tables not rendering properly

Tags: r, r-markdown

I cannot figure out why my tables in an Rmd doc are not rendering properly.
My first attempt is the standard Rmd syntax:

```
 k | Normal | Tschebyschev
------------- | ------------- | -------------
2   | `r round(100*(2*pnorm(-2)))` %   | `r round(100*(1/2^2))` %
2.5 | `r round(100*(2*pnorm(-2.5)))` % | `r round(100*(1/2.5^2))` %
3   | `r round(100*(2*pnorm(-3)),1)` % | `r round(100*(1/3^2),1)` %
4   | `r round(100*(2*pnorm(-4)),2)` % | `r round(100*(1/4^2),1)` %
```

which shows no table borders or structure.
And going the pander route is also unsuccessful:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
k=c(2,2.5,3,4);
Normal=round(100*(2*pnorm(-k)),2) 
Normal[1:2] = round(Normal[1:2])
Tschebyschev=round(100*(1/k^2),1)
Tschebyschev[1:2] = round(Tschebyschev[1:2]) 
Normal = paste(Normal, "%") 
Tschebyschev = paste(Tschebyschev, "%")
pM = cbind(k=as.character(k),Normal=Normal,Tschebyschev=Tschebyschev)
library(pander)
pandoc.table(pM, style = "grid")
```
````

My html output looks like this

[image]

Any help would be greatly useful

Thanks

Comment: try function  knitr::kable(dfr) ?

Comment: That's not a markdown, `pander` or `kable` problem, but you miss the CSS for the tables (eg if you want to have cell borders etc). You can either add some stylesheet manually, or using RStudio's `rmarkdown::render` will automatically apply some nice CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Interestingly, my tables used to render fine in the past automatically without having to specify any CSS myself. I thought the "knit HTML" would add any necessary CSS. Is this an issue with my settings?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options when it comes to tables:
Firstly, the manually constructed table renders just find for me.  What header information have you included, particularly under the `output: html_document`

Here's mine:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

k | Normal | Tschebyschev
------------- | ------------- | -------------
2   | `r round(100*(2*pnorm(-2)))` %   | `r round(100*(1/2^2))` %
2.5 | `r round(100*(2*pnorm(-2.5)))` % | `r round(100*(1/2.5^2))` %
3   | `r round(100*(2*pnorm(-3)),1)` % | `r round(100*(1/3^2),1)` %
4   | `r round(100*(2*pnorm(-4)),2)` % | `r round(100*(1/4^2),1)` %
```

If that isn't working then try adding some CSS like this to control their borders (not strictly sure all of that is needed):

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
<style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
      table, th, td, thead, tbody{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    thead {
        border-bottom: solid black;
    }
</style>
```

As far as other options, my go to is `kable` (which renders your `pM` object the same as the manual table) and if you also install `kable.extras` you can have more control over the table styles again.

For me the `pandoc.table` styles better without the `"grid"` option.

The `DT` (datatable) packages is also a great option, particularly for longer tables. When you use `datatable(pM)` the table can be filtered and searched.

However all of these will respond to CSS code, so if that is not set correctly then you will likely have problems with readability.